# Why do I get a cross-site scripting warning with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, xss

In my Rails application's view template I have to assign an instance value to a CoffeeScript variable. I did something like this:

```
:coffeescript
 44   @selected_tab = "#{@tab}"
```

It works fine, but I am getting a cross-site scripting warning:

```
Unescaped parameter value (around line 44)
find_and_preserve(Haml::Filters::Coffee.render_with_options("@selected_tab = "#{params[:tab]}" ", _hamlout.options))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off not inserting variables directly into your coffeescript.

Check out these methods: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Comment: of 3 methods, one method shows using script and that's what i am doing .

Comment: First one looks pretty insecure. It all depends on whether the escaping is contextual.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping needs to be contextual. In this blog series there are some examples of how things can go wrong: http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=91

I encourage you to read the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: So, What's the alternative ? How should I assign varaiables ?